# Aligning Two Components - React js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, alignment, mdbootstrap

I have a side pane and a footer which I want to align. 
I've css for the position of the side pane

```
#leftpane{
  background-color: #000000;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top:0;  
}
```

Component for left pane:

```
const LeftPane = () => {
return (

      <div id= "leftpane"> 
          <MDBCardTitle>Title</MDBCardTitle>
          </div>

);
};

export default LeftPane;
```

However for the footer I positioned it within the component using grid system

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div class = "container">
      <MDBFooter color="mdb-color" className="fixed-bottom offset-md-3">
        <MDBContainer className="text-center text-md-left">
          <MDBRow className="text-center text-md-left ">
            <div className='custom-control custom-switch' >
            <input type='checkbox' className='custom-control-input' id='customSwitches' />
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqbrj.png)
I want to bring the left pane out to the footer.

Comment: where is the component for your leftpane?

Comment: @IanGuimarães added the code for it there

Comment: It's not clear to me how you want this to look. Can you include a picture or a better description?

Comment: @AndyHoffman I don't have enough points to post a pic, added a diagram there, however the unwanted gap is bigger between the left pane and footer

Comment: I would add a working example on codesandbox.io/

Comment: @AndyHoffman Ive uploaded a picture now

Comment: hi @Sue, you want the footer is full from left panel to end, of left panel full 100% and overwrite left panel?